# How can I get reportlab.platytpus to let me print a title text Paragraph closer to the top of the page?

Tags: python, pdf-generation, reportlab

I’m writing a Python script using reportlab.platypus that generates a PDF document that has a title followed by four images on a PDF. The images are quite large, and I’d like to put title text in what would be the “header” of the PDF document (if this was a Word file). My pdf generation function looks like this:

```
def generate_pdf(file_name, plot_file_paths):
  doc = SimpleDocTemplate(file_name, pagesize = letter)
  content = []
  content.append(Paragraph(file_name)) # The file_name value is the title for now
  iteration_num = 0
  for plot_file_path in plot_file_paths:
    content.append(Image(plot_file_path, width=plot_width*inch, height=plot_height*inch))
    if iteration_num < 3:
      content.append(Spacer(1, 0.28*inch))
      iteration_num += 1
  doc.build(content)
```

`plot_file_paths` is a list of file names for the images that will be added to the PDF.

I’ve tried using Frames (`doc.height - top_margin - 50`) in a custom PageTemplate, and I’ve even tried combining pdfgen (to draw text at specific coordinates) with Platypus in the same function before realizing that that’s probably impossible.

I’m a very novice programmer, and I’ve been beating my head against the reportlab docs for more hours than I’d care to admit. How can I print the title text higher up on the PDF while still using Platypus for the document content?

Bonus: Once I solve this, I’m going to make the function create a multi-page PDF document from multiple source file names, that will each have their own plot images. Any help getting started with that would be greatly appreciated.